# RandomAccessFile cannot be found by compiler after being declared

Tags: java, declaration, random-access

The code below produces the following error when I try to compile it:

*cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable airplanesFile*

The error is produced by the last statement.

Why can the RandomAccessFile object not be found after it's declared?

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {
        RandomAccessFile airplanesFile = new RandomAccessFile("airplanesFile.ran", "rw");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    airplanesFile.writeUTF("Test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with variable scoping. `airplanesFile` is declared within the braces of the try block. It goes out of scope when the compiler hits the closing brace of the try block.

Declare `RandomAccessFile airplanesFile = null;` before the try statement, and alter `RandomAccessFile airplanesFile = new RandomAccessFile("airplanesFile.ran", "rw");`
 to `airplanesFile = new RandomAccessFile("airplanesFile.ran", "rw");` and your problem should go away.

Comment: Silly me... I forgot that try blocks are out of scope...
Yasin also has a good point about placing the writeUTF method call in a try block since it can throw an IOException.

I'm amazed at the speed, quantity, and quality of the responses. I'm definitely here to stay :-)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Because airplanesFile is only valid in try block. 
Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RandomAccessFile airplanesFile = null;

    try
    {
         airplanesFile = new RandomAccessFile("airplanesFile.ran", "rw");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        airplanesFile.writeUTF("Test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's out of scope. The try catch encloses the declaration.

If a variable/object is declared within a code block, inside any `{` `}` then it cannot be used outside of it. You have to do ...

```
airplanesFile.writeUTF("Test");
```

Inside the try catch, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `airplanesFile` is out of scope once the try block is done. See [Scope of Local Variable Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

That's because airplanesFile is a local variable and exists only in the try block. Try reading [about variable scopes in java](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java%20variable%20scope&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).